# problem running the core+horizon container in standalone mode

Tags: stellar-core, docker

I can start a standalone container with this command:

```
sudo docker run --rm -it -p "8000:8000" -v "/home/maxou/stellar:/opt/stellar" --name stellar stellar/quickstart --standalone
```

I can call rest commands on horizon, and when I log into the container, I see all the processes running, supervisord shows:

```
root@aba039d92900:/# supervisorctl 
horizon                          RUNNING   pid 154, uptime 0:08:08
postgresql                       RUNNING   pid 152, uptime 0:08:08
stellar-core                     RUNNING   pid 153, uptime 0:08:08
```

I then terminate the interactive container (CTRL+C)

and launch the container in background mode:

```
sudo docker run -d -p "8000:8000" -v "/home/maxou/stellar:/opt/stellar"  --name stellar stellar/quickstart --standalone
a2d8d906f7aa52644e215f336e1099441b37090b773fe6745794afc4e0f31d6c
```

Then when I try to log into it, I get a "container not running" error:

```
sudo docker exec -it stellar /bin/bash
Error response from daemon: Container a2d8d906f7aa52644e215f336e1099441b37090b773fe6745794afc4e0f31d6c is not running
```

docker ps tells me that the container exited right after starting:

```
sudo docker ps -a 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                          PORTS               NAMES
a2d8d906f7aa        stellar/quickstart   "/init -- /start --s…"   About a minute ago   Exited (0) About a minute ago                       stellar
```

What is wrong ? I would like to run the container as a service, with all the stellar services always running

## Update

If I run this command as suggested by a responder:

```
docker run -dit -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=stellar --restart always -v "/home/maxou/tstellar:/opt/stellar" -p "8000:8000" --name stellar stellar/quickstart --standalone 
fecbf92650eafb65b82fdaefb19c35113934f36ae9b4bb41b07b4ffacbdd4acf
```

Things seem to function properly:

```
root@fecbf92650ea:/# supervisorctl 
horizon                          RUNNING   pid 158, uptime 0:00:11
postgresql                       RUNNING   pid 156, uptime 0:00:11
stellar-core                     RUNNING   pid 157, uptime 0:00:11
```

Now, if I restart the container with **docker restart stellar**

things get broken:

```
root@fecbf92650ea:/# supervisorctl 
unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock refused connection
supervisor>
```

If I start the container with the console attached, I see this

```
docker start -a stellar 
running `/start --standalone'
pids are [6]

Starting Stellar Quickstart

mode: persistent
network: standalone (Standalone Network ; February 2017)
postgres: config directory exists, skipping copy
supervisor: config directory exists, skipping copy
stellar-core: config directory exists, skipping copy
horizon: config directory exists, skipping copy
postgres: already initialized
core: already initialized
Waiting for postgres to be available...
postgres: up
init-core-scp: failed!

2020-02-27T20:48:20.520 <startup> [default INFO] Config from /opt/stellar/core/etc/stellar-core.cfg
2020-02-27T20:48:20.521 <startup> [default INFO] RUN_STANDALONE enabled in configuration file - node will not function properly with most networks
2020-02-27T20:48:20.521 <startup> [default INFO] Using QUORUM_SET: {
   "t" : 1,
   "v" : [ "self" ]
}

ERROR FROM EASYLOGGING++ (LINE: 753) <ERROR> Bad file [stellar-core.2020.02.27-20:48:20.log]
    : Permission denied [13]ERROR FROM EASYLOGGING++ (LINE: 1813) <ERROR> Setting [TO_FILE] of [TRACE] to FALSE
ERROR FROM EASYLOGGING++ (LINE: 1813) <ERROR> Setting [TO_FILE] of [DEBUG] to FALSE
ERROR FROM EASYLOGGING++ (LINE: 1813) <ERROR> Setting [TO_FILE] of [FATAL] to FALSE
ERROR FROM EASYLOGGING++ (LINE: 1813) <ERROR> Setting [TO_FILE] of [ERROR] to FALSE
ERROR FROM EASYLOGGING++ (LINE: 1813) <ERROR> Setting [TO_FILE] of [VERBOSE] to FALSE
ERROR FROM EASYLOGGING++ (LINE: 1813) <ERROR> Setting [TO_FILE] of [INFO] to FALSE
...
...
...
2020-02-27T20:48:20.534 GCTI6 [Database INFO] Connecting to: postgresql://dbname=core host=localhost user=stellar password=********
2020-02-27T20:48:20.544 GCTI6 [SCP INFO] LocalNode::LocalNode@GCTI6 qSet: d05a3b
2020-02-27T20:48:20.544 GCTI6 [default INFO] Application destructing
2020-02-27T20:48:20.544 GCTI6 [default INFO] Application destroyed
2020-02-27T20:48:20.545 GCTI6 [default FATAL] Got an exception: Unable to create bucket directory: buckets [CommandLine.cpp:1015]
2020-02-27T20:48:20.545 GCTI6 [default FATAL] Please report this bug along with this log file if this was not expected [CommandLine.cpp:1016]
exited 6
```

Answer (score 2):

This is kinda old question, but can be of help to others.

For what you want to do, you need to remove current container with `docker rm stellar` to clear `stellar` namespace or just use a different name.

Then, for starting a persistent stellar node, run

```
docker run -dit --restart always -v "/str:/opt/stellar" -p "8000:8000" --name stellar stellar/quickstart --standalone
```

`-dit` is detached interactive TTY. It will run in the background as daemon and container can be connected to with `docker container attach ...` and exited with CTRL + P + Q. 
`--restart always` will make sure that whatever happens to the container, it will be restarted, even if you intentionally close it.

Comment: Thanks, I manage to get the container initialized and started using your command, but when I restart the container, it doesn't come up in the proper state.